# Hot Deploy of the Maven Project in a NetBeans 8.0.2 with Wildfly 8

Tags: maven, wildfly-8, netbeans-8, hotdeploy

Is there any possibility of performing **HOT DEPLOY** of a Maven Project in NetBeans 8.0.2 running on Wildfly 8? I need to change nbaction.xml file? Any changes in the pom.xml file? Look, I noticed that this environment is already performing the AUTO-DEPLOY, but what I need is a **HOT DEPLOY**.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

By unchecking the "Deploy on Save" no more REDEPLOY or AUTO-DELOY application. This will speed up the upgrade of static resources **ONLY**. But still do not know how to do HOT DEPLOY Java classes.

[image: Unmark 'Deploy On Save' option and Mark 'Always run build before running the application']